# How to check if value one array elements entirely exists in another array and create new array as a container of different array values in php

Tags: php, arrays

From both arrays, I want to check if it has the same value, then it will create a new array as a different array container, and this my array
**$array1**

```
"[
    {
        "inveninfoid": "298",
        "product_no": "SKU999212"
    },
    {
        "inveninfoid": "297",
        "product_no": "SKU999211"
    },
    {
        "inveninfoid": "296",
        "product_no": "SKU999210"
    },
    {
        "inveninfoid": "307",
        "product_no": "SKU999213"
    },
    {
        "inveninfoid": "308",
        "product_no": "SKU999214"
    },
    {
        "inveninfoid": "309",
        "product_no": "SKU999215"
    }
]"
```

**$array2**

```
"[
    {
        "inveninfoid": "298",
        "product_no": "SKU999212",
    },
    {
        "inveninfoid": "297",
        "product_no": "SKU999211",
    },
    {
        "inveninfoid": "296",
        "product_no": "SKU999210",
    },
    {
        "inveninfoid": "307",
        "product_no": "SKU999213",
    }
]"
```

then the result I expect is to form a new array as $array3 like this.

**$array3**

```
"[
    {
        "inveninfoid": "308",
        "product_no": "SKU999214"
    },
    {
        "inveninfoid": "309",
        "product_no": "SKU999215"
    }
]"
```

Comment: SO is not code provider, and also your "arrays" are not arrays

Comment: i debug using console.log

Answer (score 0):

> [**array_diff_assoc()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) :  Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check

You can convert `JSON` to arrays and use `array_diff_assoc`

```
$jArr1 = json_decode($j1, true);
$jArr2 = json_decode($j2, true);
$diff  = array_diff_assoc($jArr1, $jArr2);
```